# Why in this code, the semaphore counts up instead of down?

Tags: java, synchronization, locking, mutex, semaphore

I'm reading this tutorial at http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/semaphores.html

And it's counting semaphore implementation is:

```
public class CountingSemaphore {
  private int signals = 0;

  public synchronized void take() {
    this.signals++;
    this.notify();
  }

  public synchronized void release() throws InterruptedException{
    while(this.signals == 0) wait();
    this.signals--;
  }

}
```

The code seems strange to me because from what I understand, semaphore records how much available resources there are, so we should decrease the count when we `take()` and increase the count when we `release()` (and of course start with a limit).

Can anyone provide me with more insight in what's the difference between counting up and counting down approaches?

Comment: The whole `take`/`release` is backwards - `release` should be notifying, not waiting. And yes, the counting is backwards too. I suggest you contact the author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, it seems clear that the code of the two methods have been swapped and should be

```
public class CountingSemaphore {
  private int signals = 0;

  public synchronized void take() throws InterruptedException {
    while(this.signals == 0) wait();
    this.signals--;
  }

  public synchronized void release() {
     this.signals++;
     this.notify();
  }    
}
```

Indeed, the blocking method is `take` and not `release`, which can be called any number of times.

More generally, it seems natural to count upwards but it is theoretically also possible to do the exact opposite. Not sure it would be useful (and readable) though !